# Confusion between system/xbin/which and system/xbin in android

Tags: root-access, stock-android, cyanogenmod

Hi I am trying for root check of android device I am using following code to check whether the device is rooted or not but bit confused,

```
public static enum SHELL_CMD {
check_su_binary(new String[] { "/system/xbin/which", "su" });

String[] command;

SHELL_CMD(String[] command) {
    this.command = command;
}}
```

For checking binary SU in this code when I run the code with "/system/xbin/which" code shows me device is rooted(command run successfully), but if I remove "which"(i.e. "/system/xbin/") and run the code it throws me an exception that access denied.

Is there any specific significance of "/which" in rooting android device. 
I am running this code in CyanogenMod 11S(One Plus device) Thank you In advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/system/xbin/which` is the path of a program this script needs to execute (run). `/system/xbin/` is a directory, so obviously you can't execute it.

If you've never used the `which` command on your desktop GNU/Linux system, you might be interested to [read its manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?which). In this case, the script is using it to find out if the `su` command exists, and the actual program it will run.